# How two rows can be swapped in a torch tensor?

Tags: python, pytorch

```
var = [[0, 1, -4, 8],
       [2, -3, 2, 1],
       [5, -8, 7, 1]]

var = torch.Tensor(var)
```

Here, `var` is a 3 x 4 (2d) tensor. How the first and second row can be swapped to get the following 2d tensor?

```
2, -3, 2, 1 
0, 1, -4, 8
5, -8, 7, 1
```

Comment: should it be `tensor` obligatory?

Comment: yes. I want the final result as a tensor. I want to avoid conversion, say from tensor to numpy, do swapping and then again back to tensor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44944540/4901005) does not work, as some dimensions get overwritten before they are copied:

```
>>> var = [[0, 1, -4, 8],
       [2, -3, 2, 1],
       [5, -8, 7, 1]]
>>> x = torch.tensor(var)
>>> index = torch.LongTensor([1, 0, 2])
>>> x[index] = x
>>> x
tensor([[ 0,  1, -4,  8],
        [ 0,  1, -4,  8],
        [ 5, -8,  7,  1]])
```

For me, it suffices to create a new tensor (with separate underlying storage) to hold the result:

```
>>> x = torch.tensor(var)
>>> index = torch.LongTensor([1, 0, 2])
>>> y = torch.zeros_like(x)
>>> y[index] = x
```

Alternatively, you can use [`index_copy_`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.index_copy_) (following this explanation in [discuss.pytorch.org](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/moving-rows-in-tensor/4389)), although I don't see an advantage for either way at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

As other answers suggested that your permutation index should be a tensor itself, but it is not necessary. You can swap 1st and 2nd row like this:

```
>>> var
tensor([[ 0,  1, -4,  8],
        [ 2, -3,  2,  1],
        [ 5, -8,  7,  1]])

>>> var[[0, 1]] = var[[1, 0]]

>>> var
tensor([[ 2, -3,  2,  1],
        [ 0,  1, -4,  8],
        [ 5, -8,  7,  1]])
```

`var` can be a NumPy array or PyTorch tensor.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`index_select`](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-exchange-pytorch-tensor-column-position/8002/4) for this:

```py
>>> idx = torch.LongTensor([1,0,2])
>>> var.index_select(0, idx)

tensor([[ 2, -3,  2,  1],
        [ 0,  1, -4,  8],
        [ 5, -8,  7,  1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Generate the permutation index you desire:

```
index = torch.LongTensor([1,0,2])
```

Apply the permutation:

```
var[index] = var
```

Comment: This will raise an error: `RuntimeError: unsupported operation: some elements of the input tensor and the written-to tensor refer to a single memory location. Please clone() the tensor before performing the operation.`