# Reshape a torch tensor by swapping column and row indexes

Tags: python, torch

I have this tensor:

```
a = torch.tensor([[  101,   101,   101,   101],
        [14812, 16890,  2586,  2586],
        [10337,  1830,  3842,  3842],
        [ 7257, 14541,  3293,  3297]])
```

How can I reshape it into:

```
a = torch.tensor([[  101,  14812,  10337,   7257],
        [101, 16890,  1830,  14541],
        [101,  2586,  3842,  3293],
        [ 101, 2586,  3842,  3297]])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How two rows can be swapped in a torch tensor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44935176/how-two-rows-can-be-swapped-in-a-torch-tensor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [torch.T](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.t.html#torch.t) operator.

```
a.T
```

Output:

```
tensor([[  101, 14812, 10337,  7257],
        [  101, 16890,  1830, 14541],
        [  101,  2586,  3842,  3293],
        [  101,  2586,  3842,  3297]])
```